# How to fetch particular info from XML (Python)

Tags: python, xml

I need to fetch the username from this XML script. I read up on the element tree library in Python and have tried what they did with my XML file but to no avail have I succeeded. All I need is an example to fetch the username and that would be very helpful and help me understand the rest. First is the XML file and then the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <definitions name="GetEmailCert" targetNamespace="urn:GetEmailCert" 
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:tns="urn:GetEmailCert" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <message name="GetEmailCertRequest">
  <part name="username" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>
- <message name="GetEmailCertResponse">
  <part name="fullname" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <part name="email" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <part name="certificate" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>
```

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree


tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
root.tag
root.attrib

for child in root:
        print child.tag, child.attrib
#This one works 

for username in root.iter('username'):
        print username
#This one I do not know how to correctly implement
```

Comment: The `-` chars in your XML make it invalid. Are they present in the actual file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the `-` (*hyphen*) char discovered by @Robᵩ (which makes me believe that you copy/pasted the *XML* blob from user-friendly displaying tool), I discovered 2 additional ones:

- `definitions` node was not properly closed
- the *XML* had more than one root node (3 in our case). According to [[W3]: Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml):

  > Definition: There is **exactly one** element, called the root, or document element ...

Because these errors, the *XML* is still invalid:

- *Python*'s `xml.etree.ElementTree` fails to parse it
- 2 Web Browsers (*Chrome* and *IE*) fail to render it

After fixing all the errors, the *XML* looks like this (note that I've encapsulated everything in a *root* node (that I called `root`)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <root>
    <definitions name="GetEmailCert" targetNamespace="urn:GetEmailCert"
      xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
      xmlns:tns="urn:GetEmailCert" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
    <message name="GetEmailCertRequest">
      <part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetEmailCertResponse">
      <part name="fullname" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="email" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="certificate" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
  </root>
```

Code-wise: there are more ways (including *XML* libraries) of achieving your goal; I chose the one that uses [[Python]: xml.etree.ElementTree — The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (as you started implementing).

Now, I didn't quite understand what did you mean by "*fetch the username*", but I assumed that it's the `<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>` node. Considering that my assumption is correct, here's the *tree*-like approach (it's supposed to be general):

- The *XML* document from *test.xml* has one *root* node (tagged `root`)
- The *root* node has **0 or more** (2 for our *XML*) *message* nodes (tagged `message`)
- Each *message* node has **0 or more** *part* nodes (tagged `part`)
- Each *part* node **may or may not** have a *name* attribute whose value is `username`; if it does, then it's **the node** that we want (print it)

And the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def main():
    tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
    root_node = tree.getroot()

    message_nodes = root_node.iter("message")
    for message_node in message_nodes:
        part_nodes = message_node.iter("part")
        for part_node in part_nodes:
            if part_node.attrib.get("name", "") == "username":
                print(ET.tostring(part_node))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```